# Is GNU Hurd using the same principles as Minix 3 for self healing?

Tags: unix, gnu

Minix3 has a reincarnation server that can restart drivers if they crash or end up in a infinitive loop. It can even restart the disk driver by keeping a shadow copy of the same or an older version of the driver and thus being able to recover and self-heal from most errors.
In other words Minix 3 is built to be a very reliable kernel at the cost of some performance.

Is GNU Hurd...

- Built on the same principles as Minix 3?
- Featuring something similar to the reincarnation server and if so , how does it differ?
- Able to recover from a (disk) driver failure transparent to processes running in user space?!

In short I am trying to learn the basics about the good, the bad and the ugly for both systems and how they differ from eachother from a practical point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [GNU Hurd web site](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd.html), GNU Hurd is under active development and there is no stable version.  [Towards a New Strategy of OS Design](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd-paper.html) indicates that GNU Hurd development is taking a similar micro kernel approach as Minix 3 with the idea of providing interface layers providing a mechanism to port applications from other Unix like operating systems.

However [Minix 3 read me](http://www.minix3.org/other/read-more.html) indicates there is a stable version.

It appears the main difference is that Minix 3 is a usable operating system where as GNU Hurd is under development and according to this [Wikipedia article on GNU Hurd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Hurd), is considered to be unsuitable for production environments.  Where as this [Wikipedia article on Minix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minix) indicates that Minix 3 could be considered a production ready operating system and some people are using it.